# how to group columns without aggregation function in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following code written in pyspark sql that looks like this:

```
dep_cus = sc_sql.sql("select cid, sum(trans_amnt) as run_bal, max(ds) as last_tran_date, mark_seg, province, local_body, branch, acc_type, int_rate from dep_sdf_temp group by cid, mark_seg, province, local_body, branch, acc_type, int_rate")
```

How can I write this code in pandas?

Comment: Hi Subash, can you please edit your post to show what you have tried in pandas and where your are stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
dep_cus = dep_sdf_temp.groupby(['cid', 'mark_seg', 'province', 'local_body', 'branch', 'acc_type', 'int_rate'])
                      .agg({'ds':'max', 'trans_amnt':'sum'})
                      .rename(columns={'ds':'last_tran_date', 'trans_amnt': 'run_bal'})
```